# I'm creating a quiz which is for primary school students

Tags: python, sorting

The scores should be recorded onto a .txt file related to the class of the pupil. The teacher should then be able to choose a class.  the teacher can then choose whether to see the results in alphabetical order, average score of each student from the latest three results or highest to lowest score.

I have done the class part but I am having trouble writing code for the teacher choosing a class and choosing a way of sorting the results.

This is my code so far:

```
import random


score=0
name= input('What is your name?')

def class_():
    classNum=input('What class are you in 1,2 or 3?')
    global inputfile
    if classNum=="1": inputfile=open("class1.txt","a")
    elif classNum=="2": inputfile=open("class2.txt","a")
    else: inputfile=open("class3.txt", "a")


print ('Welcome to my quiz', str(name))
print ('You will be asked 10 random questions to test your maths skills')
input("Press Enter to continue...")

range(10)
operatorList=["+","-","*"]
numQuestions=10



for q in range (numQuestions):
    op=random.choice(operatorList)
    first_num = random.randint(0,10)
    second_num = random.randint(0,10)
    print(first_num,op,second_num)
    expression = "%d %s %d" % (first_num, op, second_num) 
    answer = eval(expression) 
    reply = int(input('Enter the answer: '))

    if (reply==answer):
        print("Well done, you got it right!")
        score=score+1
    else:
         print("Unlucky! You got it wrong")


print ('\n')
print ('\n')


print("Well done", str(name))
print("You scored", str(score)+"/10")

class_()
inputfile.write(name + "," + str(score)+ "\n")
inputfile.close()
```

I think you have to create a brand new piece of code just for the teacher

**NEW CODE**

ok this is the start of my new code:

```
viewclass= input("choose a class number and either alphabetically, average or highest?")


if viewclass=='1 alphabetically':
    with open('class1.txt', 'r') as r:
        for line in sorted(r):
             print(line, end='')

elif viewclass=='2 alphabetically':
    with open('class2.txt', 'r') as r:
        for line in sorted(r):
             print(line, end='')

elif viewclass=='3 alphabetically':
    with open('class3.txt', 'r') as r:
        for line in sorted(r):
             print(line, end='')
```

so I've done the alphabetical part but would i have to change the first code to only allow the 3 latest scores to be stored for each student or could I add it to my second one.

Comment: "I think you have to create a brand new piece of code just for the teacher". Correct. And if you want help on that new code you need to attempt to write it and show it to us, with a short sample of typical input.

Comment: ok just trying to do it now. I've created a way of doing the alphabetical bit but struggling with just storing the latest three scores from a student to work out the average score for them.

Comment: done sorry i'm new to this :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a dumb question so I upvoted it. However you should really learn how to handle classes and work with objects in python if you want to make a nice application of that nature.
Bellow I show you some tips on how to abstract the problem into python classes, it's not good and I don't quite know what you need but it's a start.

```
class Class(object):
    def __init__(self, num, name, input_file):
        self.name = name
        self.num = num
        self.input_file = input_file
        self.students = []
        #so far it's just an empty list

    #add methods that read in the students from a file
    #parse it for info you need
    def parse():
        #parse self.input_file for info you need
        pass

class Classes(object):
    def __init__(self, input_file):
        self.input_file = input_file
        self.all_classes = []
    #this parse function should read in from a file
    #of all classes, and instantiate a new Class
    #object and put them in self.all_classes
    #this is the class that enables you to select
    #which Class you want, and Class object should
    #have methods for calculating average, per student
    #grade etc....
    def parse():
        #parse the file to fill self.all_classes
        pass


classes = Classes(input_file="all_classes.txt")
#this should return a Classes object named classes
#that object should contain a list of all Class objects
#those objects should have methods to retrieve avg grade etc...
```

and then in the IDLE you could have stuff like:

```
>>> classes.all_classes
[]
>>> classes.input_file
'all_classes.txt'
>>> specific_class = classes.all_classes["specific_class_identifier"]
>>> specific_class["specific_quiz_identifier"].avgGrade()
```

I recommend you plan out what exactly do you want to achieve ahead of actually programing it. Especially your data files in which you keep your info. I.e. they could be as simple as csv separated files:
**all_classes.txt**

```
class1a,"class1a.txt"
```

**specific_class.txt**

```
"Student Student","quiz1: grade","quiz2: grade"
"Student Student","quiz1: grade","quiz2: grade"
```

or could be complex files like JSON etc....